# Why is Java's array copy method behaving this way?

Tags: java, arrays

The following code uses Java's array copy method in various ways:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] copyFrom={'s','n','a','d','g'};
    char[] copyto=new char[7];
    System.arraycopy(copyFrom, 1, copyto, 0, 3);
    System.out.println(new String (copyto));
    System.arraycopy(copyFrom, 1, copyto, 1, 3);
    System.out.println(new String (copyto));
    System.arraycopy(copyFrom, 1, copyto, 2, 3);
    System.out.println(new String (copyto));
    System.arraycopy(copyFrom, 1, copyto, 4, 3);
    System.out.println(new String (copyto));
}
```

And this is the output:

> nad
>   nnad
>   nnnad
>   nnnanad

why is `"n"` being repeated?

Comment: Because each call to `arraycopy` is copying "nad" to a different location in the target array, and those target locations overlap.  See the [API doc for arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-).

Comment: because you are always copying from the same index of copyFrom which is `copyFrom[1]`

Comment: but how they are overlaping . i am printing them in different lines.. then is it possible ..?? can you please explain it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you use one copyto array, I show you in comment

```
   char[] copyFrom={'s','n','a','d','g'};
    char[] copyto=new char[7]; // copyto = {'','','','','','',''}
    System.arraycopy(copyFrom, 1, copyto, 0, 3); // copyto = {'n','a','d','','','',''}
    System.out.println(new String (copyto));
    System.arraycopy(copyFrom, 1, copyto, 1, 3); // copyto = {'n','n','a','d','','',''}, 
// because first element 'n' stay from previous step

   System.out.println(new String (copyto));  
   System.arraycopy(copyFrom, 1, copyto, 2, 3); // from previous step you have {'n', 'n'} and replace only 2, 3 and 4 elements

//  {'n','n','n','a','d','',''}, 
    System.out.println(new String (copyto));
    System.arraycopy(copyFrom, 1, copyto, 4, 3); // from previous step you have {'n', 'n', 'n'} and replace only 4, 5 and 6 elements
    System.out.println(new String (copyto));
}
```

You should create new copyto arrays every times:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] copyFrom={'s','n','a','d','g'};
    char[] copyto=new char[7];
    System.arraycopy(copyFrom, 1, copyto, 0, 3);
    System.out.println(new String (copyto));
    copyto=new char[7];
    System.arraycopy(copyFrom, 1, copyto, 1, 3);
    System.out.println(new String (copyto));
    copyto=new char[7];
    System.arraycopy(copyFrom, 1, copyto, 2, 3);
    System.out.println(new String (copyto));
    copyto=new char[7];
    System.arraycopy(copyFrom, 1, copyto, 4, 3);
    System.out.println(new String (copyto));
}
```

Comment: i got it .. @Viacheslav